# HtmlUnit's DomElement can't save state of XPath result

Tags: html, xml, xpath

when I search big document sometimes I need to save result of big XPath expression, but if I try to store XPath result in DomElement object and make new XPath query just on block of code that I've pointed to DomElement object, I get results based on whole document. For example:

```
DomElement block = page.getByXPath("//div[@class='block_of_code']");
System.out.println(block.getByXPath("//span[@class='red']"));
```

So, first line will fetch all divs on the page with class='block_of_code'. But when I try to print out all span elements from block object I get back all span element that are on the page, not only in that block.

Is there an alternative (in HtmlUnit package preferably) where to store small chunks of html blocks and do manipulation by xPath just on it, not whole page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XPath expression starting with a `/` character will always query the entire document, even if you pass a context node to the function.

To make a query relative to the context node, you can start it with a `.` character.

The following should achieve what you want:

```
DomElement block = page.getByXPath("//div[@class='block_of_code']");
System.out.println(block.getByXPath(".//span[@class='red']"));
```